# Stopping python-vlc: player.stop() doesn't work

Tags: python, pafy, python-vlc

I am trying to play a youtube video using pafy and vlc:

```
def run(command, args, voice_instance):
    if command == "pune":
        search_query = " ".join(args)
        result = YoutubeSearch(search_query, max_results=10).to_dict()[0]

        video_title = result["title"]
        url_suffix = result["url_suffix"]

        url = f"https://www.youtube.com/{url_suffix}"
        video = pafy.new(url)
        best = video.getbest()
        playurl = best.url
        Instance = vlc.Instance("--no-video")
        player = Instance.media_player_new()
        Media = Instance.media_new(playurl)
        Media.get_mrl()
        player.set_media(Media)
        voice_instance.say(f'Pun {video_title}')
        player.play()
    
    if "oprește" in command:
        print('1')
        player.stop()
        print('2')
```

It plays the video, but when i say `opreste` it prints 1 then stops, and the video is still playing.

Any ideas on how could i fix this ?

Comment: We probably need to see more of your code to see how you're calling run to give you a real answer but from what you've posted it looks likely that player is going to be undefined when you call it a second time.  You need to keep track of the player variable somewhere.

Comment: This is just an addon for https://github.com/AlfredoSequeida/karen
That is my entire code without imports..i can't think of any way to keep track of the player variable..i tried some things but nothing is working. Do you know how could i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shooting off the hip, but if all you can do is provide a single function, maybe you can store your player as a global variable?

```py
def run(command, args, voice_instance):

    if globals().get('player'):
        instance = globals()['instance']
        player = globals()['player']
    else:
        instance = globals()['instance'] = vlc.Instance("--no-video")
        player = globals()['player'] = instance.media_player_new()    

    if command == "pune":
        search_query = " ".join(args)
        result = YoutubeSearch(search_query, max_results=10).to_dict()[0]

        video_title = result["title"]
        url_suffix = result["url_suffix"]

        url = f"https://www.youtube.com/{url_suffix}"
        video = pafy.new(url)
        best = video.getbest()
        playurl = best.url

        media = instance.media_new(playurl)
        media.get_mrl()
        player.set_media(media)

        voice_instance.say(f'Pun {video_title}')
        player.play()
    
    if "oprește" in command:
        print('1')
        player.stop()
        print('2')
        # and possibly garbage collect the player
        # del globals()['player']
        # del globals()['instance']
```